# How can I uncache imported module in python?

Tags: python

This is really freaking me out. My project looks like this

```
.
|-- main.py
|-- classes
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- exceptions.py
```

In those `exceptions.py`, I initally created one exception called `SecurityError`:

```
class SecurityError(Exception):
    pass
```

I included the file in `main.py` using `from classes.exceptions import *` and `SecurityError` normally works when I just `raise` it.

Afterwards, I also added `FilesystemError`, but whenever using it, I get:

> **global name 'FilesystemError' is not defined**

I tried to delete `*.pyc` files in `classes` directory but it has no effect. Any changes to the `exceptions.py` take no effect, including any ridiculous ones that make the file invalid:

```
class FileFOO BAR BAZ systemError(Exception):
    pass

class SecurityErr foo bar bazor(Exception):
    pass
```

The program still behaves as if the file never changed since the first run. I don't think this behaviour has anything to do with intuitive programming - if there's cache, it should be in that directory.

I am running the python directly from command line:

```
C:\programing\python\MyProject>py -2 main.py
```

Comment: How are you running/testing? Are you testing within the same python session since the first run?

Comment: I guess I should've mentioned that - I just run `C:\\ ... \MyProject>py -2 main.py` in WIndows command line every time. That is, I sure do quit the process unless it forks and persists in background.

Comment: How are you "using" `FilesystemError`? The message `global name ...` indicates that you are referring to it as a global name somewhere. Are you doing that from within `exceptions.py`? If not, did you actually import it from the module where you're trying to use it? Can you please include the *full* stack trace in your question?

Comment: I use it using `raise` and I added details on how I include it. It should be notable that `SecurityError` normally works when `raise`d. So unless there's some really weird kind of name problem, the file is just cached.

Comment: My bad, I missed the `from classes.exceptions import *` part. I would suggest that you change that to explicit imports, including `from classes.exceptions import FilesystemError` - you should get clearer error messages. Also, a full stack trace would still be helpful.

Comment: Try doing `from classes import exceptions` and then `print exceptions.__file__` to see where it is importing the file from.

Comment: There isn't full stack trace because I receive the error over XML-RPC protocol. Renaming the file fixed the problem, so this removes any doubts about it being a cache problem.

Comment: There is a builtin Python module called `exceptions`.  This shouldn't be imported if you're using `from classes.exceptions import *`, but if you have anything else anywhere that is doing something like `import exceptions` it could be causing problems.

Comment: (Also, using the from module import * is **highly** discouraged because it does not tell you what you import. If you are doing: from exceptions import *, you will get everything in the builtin polluting your namespace, and none of your desired variables.

Comment: Guys I am importing **classes.exceptions** - so there's no conflict. This is why possibility to make folders exists in the first place! So that we can have multiple files with same name on computer. I'm not sure what's unclear about that...

Comment: If you're running the program directly from the command line, why are you receiving the error over XML-RPC?

Comment: Can you create an MCVE?  'cause I'm pretty sure I can create something that looks like what you say that will work fine.

Comment: `>>> from classes.exceptions import *`
`>>> FilesystemError`
`<class 'classes.exceptions.FilesystemError'>`

Answer (score 0):

Confusing errors of the form `global name 'XXX' is not defined` typically mean that you are shadowing a standard library module. You must rename your `exceptions` module.

Comment: It works when I renamed it, ran the program and renamed it back. So I may be shadowing something, but it's not straightforward the cause of the problem. Also the fact that I use `classes.exceptions` pretty much clears any name conflict problems.